# Liquidsoap Icecast request.dynamic error

Tags: icecast, liquidsoap

I would like to create dynamic playlist with liquidesoap and icecast. I've just copied the tutorial from the liquidsoap website but unfortunately it does not work.

This is my code:

```
def get_next() =
  result = list.hd(get_process_lines("/var/www/radiod/yii program-generator/next-track 1"))

  # Create and return a request using this result
  request.create(result)
end

# Create the source
s = request.dynamic(id="s", get_next)

# Output
source = output.icecast(%mp3, host="localhost", port=8000, mount="opera.mp3", password="asd123", s)
```

I get this error message when I run the check command:

```
Invalid value at line 9, char 20-37: That source is fallible.
```

So, the problem will be around this line:

```
s = request.dynamic(id="s", get_next)
```

Can you help me what could be the failure?

Thanking you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://savonet.sourceforge.net/doc-svn/quick_start.html covers *"That source is fallible."* in detail. Might want to go through the whole page.

Comment: Thank you! I've checked the documentation but it seems not so attentively. The fallible=true was the solution to my problem.